# Issue with gcs upload of an image file

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm facing an issue in uploading image file, so far I've seen it with png files, into a gcs buckets specific folder. The env logs indicate that it has been uploaded successfully but the file is nowhere to be found. There is no TTL and I've also taken into account eventual consistency. It doesn't appear even after an hour. The code is written in java and makes use of a writechannel to write and is flushed post that as per documentation.

I'm not sure what's happening here and have exhausted the possibilities I could think of, such as corrupted test data, different formats and missed to handle for a specific scenario. Everything seems to check out while debugging in local but when trying out the same post deployment in k8s, the issue persists. Any info on a direction to look into would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, it will be very hard to help if you don't show the errors and code you're using

Comment: Do you mean it works locally but not on GKE? If so, did you test the container locally? In addition, can you activate the audit logs on Cloud Storage (write) to be sure the object is correctly written; you will also have the full path. Can you also check the bucket with the gcloud CLI?

Comment: @Puteri thats the thing, there are no errors

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have not tested the container locally, I wasn't aware that's an option. Let me see if I will get access to do the thing you have listed out. Thanks for your help!